# Problem with calculating HMAC of a string with python

Tags: python, cryptography, sha256, hmac, message-authentication-code

I am trying to write a program that calculates hmac of a string. I am allowed to use hashlib library but not hmac. Here is my code:

```py
from hashlib import sha256

def string_to_decimal(string):
    res = ''
    for char in string:
        res += hex(ord(char))[2:]
    return int(res, 16)

def decimal_to_string(number):
    hex_number = hex(number)[2:]
    hex_number = hex_number[::-1]
    res = ''
    for i in range(0, len(hex_number), 2):
        if i + 1 < len(hex_number):
            res += chr(int(hex_number[i + 1] + hex_number[i], 16))
        else:
            res += chr(int(hex_number[i], 16))

    return res[::-1]

def calculate_ipad_opad(block_size, ipad, opad):
    res_ipad = 0
    res_opad = 0
    for i in range(block_size // 8):
        res_ipad = (res_ipad * 256) + ipad
        res_opad = (res_opad * 256) + opad
    return res_ipad, res_opad

def integer_to_bytes(number):
    res = list()
    while number > 0:
        res.append(number % 256)
        number //= 256
    
    return bytes(res[::-1])

block_size = 512

msg = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
key = 'key'

ipad = 54
opad = 92

block_ipad, block_opad = calculate_ipad_opad(block_size, ipad, opad)

key_decimal = string_to_decimal(key)
si = key_decimal ^ block_ipad
so = key_decimal ^ block_opad

a = sha256(integer_to_bytes(so) + sha256(integer_to_bytes(si) + msg.encode()).digest())

print(a.digest())
```

I know the key length is not more than the block size. I used [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#:%7E:text=In%20cryptography%2C%20an%20HMAC%20(sometimes,and%20a%20secret%20cryptographic%20key.) to write the code. But it doesn't work properly. Could you please help me with that???

**EDIT:**
I expected the output of the code to be `f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8`. But the output is `3d6243123b984bcc17cb96eb61c2b47d27545c3a9119b623be7932e846bf0643`.

Comment: @jps thank you for your comment. I edited that.

Comment: how did you calculate expected output ?

Comment: @furas: I tried with https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html hmac sha256 and got the expected value that OP posted.

Comment: @ssaf Best to look up or generate intermediate values for the various steps using a known good implementation.

Comment: Uh, I don't see that `ipad` and `opad` have the right values.  These should be byte arrays of the given value, not a *multiplication with* the value.

Comment: your calculations doesn't fit me to description on Wikipedia. You don't pad key (`key ← Pad(key, blockSize)`) you don't create bytes list with repeated values `0x5c` and `0x36`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes multiplicating ipad to 256 shifts the ipad 8 bits to left. i.e 0x36 * 0x100 = 0x3600. then adding the result with 0x36 makes it repeated twice. i.e 0x3600 + 0x36 = 0x3636. this process is repeated for block_size times

Comment: Ugh. OK, don't know what is wrong with `<<` and really you should do this byte-by-byte, but I guess this may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key must be padded with 0x00 values on the right side up to the block size of the digest (if the key size is smaller than the block size, which is the case here). You can achieve this by e.g. adding in `string_to_decimal()` just before the `return`:

```
res = res.ljust(64 * 2, "0")
```

With this change, the expected result is provided.

For an implementation, it is better to use a more detailed specification of the algorithm, e.g. [FIPS PUB 198-1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.198-1.pdf) instead of the highly abbreviated description in Wikipedia. Furthermore, you are on the safe side if official [test vectors](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/Message-Authentication) are applied.

---

The conversion to decimal numbers is actually not necessary, i.e. it is possible to work directly with bytes like objects, which simplifies the implementation considerably:

```py
from hashlib import sha256

msg = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
key = 'key'

block_size_bytes = 64

block_opad_bytes = b'\x5c' * block_size_bytes
block_ipad_bytes = b'\x36' * block_size_bytes
key_bytes = key.encode().ljust(block_size_bytes, b'\0')

si_bytes = bytes([a ^ b for (a, b) in zip(block_ipad_bytes, key_bytes)]) 
so_bytes = bytes([a ^ b for (a, b) in zip(block_opad_bytes, key_bytes)]) 

a = sha256(so_bytes + sha256(si_bytes + msg.encode()).digest())

print(a.digest().hex()) # f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```